# Data removed from SQL but still visible in UI

Tags: javascript, sql, web

I am creating a web page to show a table from SQL. I’ve added commands in js so the user can add, edit or update data in the UI. However, when I delete a datapoint through UI, only the data in SQL is deleted but it’s still visible in the UI. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effects of database operations don't percolate to the frontend automatically without refreshing the page. You need to implement logic to do this.

For example, a websocket that connects your frontend to your backend and listens to changes, which the backend sends to the frontend whenever the db changes. Then the frontend can make the corresponding changes in the UI.

Or, in this particular case, since you know the user action is going to result in a deletion of data, you may not even need a socket. Just wait for the async HTTP request to complete successfully and then change the UI accordingly. It does mean, however, that anyone else looking at the same page won't see the data disappear unless they refresh the page, which is why the socket approach may be better depending on your needs.

UI frameworks typically achieve data addition/changes/removals through two-way data binding, but you could also manually delete DOM nodes that hold the deleted data.